# SQL stored procedure statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got the following but I can't add `'` between the `@Category` and `@Subcateory` , tried running on SQL and its proven that it needs the `'` else it won't work someone help me on this:

`Train = @Train AND Sub= @Sub`

I tried

```
'''+@train+'''
'@train'
```

etc

```
FROM [Items]
WHERE 
     Description LIKE '%' + @SearchDescription + '%' 
     AND Claimed = @ClaimedCheck 
     AND RetentionEnd = @RetentionEndCheck 
     AND Train = (''''+ @Train +'''') AND Sub = (''''+ @Sub +'''')
```

It's returning me empty result but it can work with just

```
FROM [Items]
WHERE 
     Description LIKE '%' + @SearchDescription + '%' 
     AND Claimed = @ClaimedCheck 
     AND RetentionEnd = @RetentionEndCheck
```

### Answer:

```
@Something VARCHAR(100)
```

I edited the varchar to `VARCHAR(100)` instead of just `VARCHAR`. It worked.

Comment: can you please add more code?  it is very unclear what you need

Comment: Please please please add more details... the script you're running, project context, etc.

Comment: OK. Well, what values are you passing into the sproc for @Train and @Sub, and are you sure there are any rows that match? Try adding `Train, @Train, Sub, @Sub` to the `select` part of your last query - then maybe you can see what's going on.

Comment: You probably don't need `''''` after all, unless your data has quotes around it and the input you're passing in does not.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is too general to provide a concrete answer, but if you are concatenating strings in a select here are some common practices:

```
-- Escape single quote character
SELECT Name, 'Someone\'s name' AS ConcatedName
FROM table
```

or:

```
-- Use two single quote characters to mimic the effect of 
-- escaping one single quote character.
SELECT Name, 'Someone''s name' AS ConcatedName
FROM table;
```

or:

```
-- Concatenate strings and columns
SELECT CONCAT('Quantity Per Unit for ', ProductName, ' is ', QuantityPerUnit)
        AS "Product Details"
FROM products;
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to concatenating strings.

This can be done with the following sort of query:

```
SELECT @Category + ' ' + @SubCategory
```

If both of these variables are `nvarchar` then they will concatenate and become one string output.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

```
'''' + @train + ''''
```

If @train's value was `choo choo`, this would evaluate to `'choo choo'`.

Comment: Cant work i updated my original code

Comment: Please update your question and explain what you mean by "cant work" - does it give an error? Not find your rows? What?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you want, but if you want to escape single quotes, you do it by adding an extra quote, i.e. `''`. To add it inbetween two other fields, you'd do something like:

```
SELECT @Category + '''' + @SubCategory
```

In `''''`, the first and last single quote starts and ends a literal string, while the two in the middle escapes the actual single quote to be included in the string.

So, based on your example, you'd use:

```
'''' + @train + ''''
```